# jQuery for loop not functioning

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a for loop statement that doesn't loop, here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=1;i<=30;i++){
        $('img[alt="sample'+i+'"]').click(function(){
            var changeImage = $('img[alt="sample'+i+'"]').attr('src');
            var changeText = $('img[alt="sample'+i+'"]').attr('alt');
            $('img[alt="main image"]').attr('src', changeImage);
            $('h4#imageTitleHead').text(changeText);
        });
    }
});
```

the `i` won't loop and when I check the source code the code is still the same.. like this `$('img[alt="sample'+i+'"]')` it didn't change to number and did not loop at all.. Please help.. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do a loop if you can do this:

First add any class to images which `alt` is `sample[NUMBER]` (e.g. `loopImages`):

```
<img src="image.png" alt="sample1" class="loopImages">
```

Now, the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.loopImages').click(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        var changeImage = current.attr('src');
        var changeText = current.attr('alt');

        $('img[alt="main image"]').attr('src', changeImage);
        $('h4#imageTitleHead').text(changeText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a hassle between the `i` from the loop and the callback function.
There is only one `i` variable provided, that will be 31 after the last iteration of the loop.
But jQuery provides a handy way to access the clicked object as the context object (aka `this`).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
    $('img[alt="sample'+i+'"]').click(function() {
      var clickedObject = $(this); // wrap it in a jquery
      var changeImage = clickedObject.attr('src');
      var changeText = clickedObject.attr('alt');
      $('img[alt="main image"]').attr('src', changeImage);
      $('h4#imageTitleHead').text(changeText);
    });
  }
});
```

That should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

The loop itself is fine... http://jsfiddle.net/

Let's see what else is wrong...

Wait, nevermind, editting

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be solved with a fairly simple selector.

Here's what it would look like:

```
$('img[alt*="sample"]')...
```

You could also write the function once outside of the for loop instead of re-declaring it every time the loop runs. ex.:

```
function bindAllImages(image){
    // same code in here
}

$('img[alt*="sample"]').bind('click', bindAllImages(image);
```

Also here's a JSFiddle illustrating the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/JYCLA/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JYCLA/3/ << Updated with multiple images